# SpecTree - is there a way to hide an endpoint from swagger

Tags: python, flask

I am currently working on a Flask project and using Spectree version 1.2.8 for API validation. For certain endpoints, I want to restrict their visibility on the Swagger UI documentation generated by Spectree to keep them private or for internal use only.

Could anyone guide me on whether it's possible to exclude specific routes from being displayed in the Swagger UI with Spectree 1.2.8?

I've searched through the Spectree documentation and tried looking into the configuration options, but I haven't found a clear solution that addresses this need directly.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Probably, the most straightforward approach to achieve this functionality is to request it as a feature from the Spectree developers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular scenario, it became evident that leveraging Spectree to achieve the desired outcome was unfeasible. As a result, I made the decision to bypass the Spectree decorator for the specific route in question. To ensure that validation was still rigorously applied, I turned to Pydantic, utilizing it to perform validations at both the initiation and termination points of the route. This approach allowed for a more tailored validation process, ensuring that the unique requirements of the route were met effectively.